Try using Paho 2.+ Python MQTT with TPM
In my project we need to secure the MQTT communication with Trusted Plattform Module TPM2.0.
The paho Python script for a MQTT communication with a Iot broker is working, but with TPM is failing. Meaning errors like this:
Setting of the TLS connection failed. Exception = [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3916)

are popping up.
No connection with a device certificate generated from a local private key (generated with TPM).
Questions:

Is the paho library even capable of handling TPM backed MQTT connections and communication?

If yes what is the general workflow for accomplishing that?


# Configure TLS settings
self.__client.tls_set(
                ca_certs="./certs/CA.crt",
                certfile="./certs/device-cert.crt",
                keyfile=None,
                tls_version=self.__tls_version,
                alpn_protocols=alpn_protocols
                )

conn_err = self.__client.connect(self.__brocker, self.__port)

Normally for TPM there is a key handle instead of a private key. Ideally, the paho lib should get the key handle and use it to establish the connection to the MQTT broker instead of a private key.

I think you are going to be out of luck here, it's been a while since I played with TPMs but that was when using openssl directly and you had to set the right "engine". I'm not sure Python is 1) using OpenSSL under the covers, 2) support setting an engine
